# how to parse special characters like Danish in android?

Tags: android, json, special-characters

hi am doing a json parsing in this i want to post some data if  use Danish character(æøåÆØÅ*) the data s is not been uploaded to the server.i  need to know how post this data to server and also how do i get the posted special character to my app .please help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i sorted out the answer use UTF-8 Encoding and decoding for solving this issue

encode the value  when passing it to a server and decode that when we need to display it from server to our app

URLENCODING-pass value to server

```
String value="å";//This is a special character
try {
        value=URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF8");
        System.out.println("value------"+value);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The out put will be **value------%C3%A5**

we can pass this value to server.

now that we have pass the values to server and if  we  need  to show it in some places in our app we need to decode the value from server and we will get the result data like this

```
String value="%C3%A5";
    try {
        value=URLDecoder.decode(value, "UTF8");
        System.out.println("value------"+value);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The out put will be **value------å**

This is how we pass danish or any other special charaters to server by parsing